# How to place text flushed right in math mode (next to equation number)?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have equations like this:

```
\documentclass[DVI=17]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\FA}{FA}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RA}{RA}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MD}{MD}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RD}{RD}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AD}{AD}
\newcommand{\eqname}[1]{\tag*{#1~(\theequation)}\refstepcounter{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \ln\left[ \frac{A(2\tau)}{A(0)} \right] =  -D \gamma^2 \delta^2 \left( \Delta - \frac13\delta \right)G^2 \eqname{Stejskal-Tanner}
  \label{eq:st}
\end{equation}

\newcommand{\FASUMI}[1]{\left(\lambda_{#1} - \MD\right)^2}
\newcommand{\FASUM}{\FASUMI{1} + \FASUMI{2} + \FASUMI{3}}
\begin{align}
  \AD &= \lambda_{\parallel} = \lambda_1 {\eqname{Axial Diffusivity}} \\
  \RD &= \lambda_{\perp} = \frac{\lambda_2 + \lambda_3}{2} \eqname{Radial Diffusivity} \\
  \MD &= \frac{1}{3}\sum \lambda_i \eqname{Mean Diffusivity} \\
  \FA &= \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\FASUM}}{\sqrt{\sum \lambda_i^2}} \eqname{Fractional Anisotropy}\label{eq:fa} \\
  \RA &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{\sqrt{\FASUM}}{\MD} \eqname{Relative Anisotropy}
\end{align}

In text we refer \Cref{eq:st} and \Cref{eq:fa}.
\end{document}
```

which renders to:

[image]

While the rendering of the equations is exactly what I am searching, the referencing is not. I want to use cleveref to save the "Equation" word. Ideally I want to have such a text: `we refer Equation (1)..` best with `\Cref`. Therefore I just need to find a way to put the equation name not into the tag but at the same place. It should work for align and equation the same way. So, what I am really asking is, how to put the eq. name next to its number, but without using `\tag`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `fleqn` package to achieve it.

```
\documentclass[DVI=17]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\FA}{FA}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RA}{RA}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MD}{MD}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RD}{RD}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AD}{AD}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\phantom{\text{Stejskal-Tanner}}&&
  \ln\left[ \frac{A(2\tau)}{A(0)} \right] =  -D \gamma^2 \delta^2 \left( \Delta - \frac13\delta \right)G^2 
&&\text{Stejskal-Tanner}
  \label{eq:st}
\end{flalign}

\newcommand{\FASUMI}[1]{\left(\lambda_{#1} - \MD\right)^2}
\newcommand{\FASUM}{\FASUMI{1} + \FASUMI{2} + \FASUMI{3}}
\begin{flalign}
&&  \AD &= \lambda_{\parallel} = \lambda_1 & \text{Axial Diffusivity} \\
&&  \RD &= \lambda_{\perp} = \frac{\lambda_2 + \lambda_3}{2} &\text{Radial Diffusivity} \\
&&  \MD &= \frac{1}{3}\sum \lambda_i &\text{Mean Diffusivity} \\
&&  \FA &= \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\FASUM}}{\sqrt{\sum \lambda_i^2}} &\text{Fractional Anisotropy}\label{eq:fa} \\
&&  \RA &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{\sqrt{\FASUM}}{\MD} &\text{Relative Anisotropy}
\end{flalign}

In text we refer \Cref{eq:st} and \Cref{eq:fa}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: in equation 1, I used a `\phantom` of the label to demonstrate how to center the equation relative to the page centerline.  One could achieve the actual result in your question, by eliminating the `\phantom`, and just leaving a `&&` prior to the equation itself.